# pypi package automatically uninstalling and upgrading other things?

Tags: python, django

I have a pypi package that I distribute that requires django, in my setup.py I have this...

```
install_requires = ["Django"]
```

then in the egg I have a requires.txt file that is like this...

```
Django
```

Now I just made a new version and uploaded it to `pypi` and did `pip install -U mypackage` and it uninstalled my current django 1.10 and reinstalled django 1.10.1.

How can I make it leave the users Django version alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your version dependencies like

```
install_requires = ["Django>=1.8"]
```

So that if the user has `Django` less than `1.8` then only it will upgrade.